# How to unset marcro of netbean

Tags: netbeans

I have clicked keyboad during I use netbean IDE, but I don't know which key and then it appar marcro set. Mean that create shortcut key in netbean. At those I create one shortcut key is I clicked key space + key inter 
now my computer can't click the key space. When I click it not action.
As I think if we unset marcro it will work.

Please help me

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools/Options/Editor/Macros

There you can define and edit macros and also set the shortcut (to none in your case)

Comment: Thank so much I can do it as well now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete an assigned shortcut in Netbeans got to: menu "Tools" --> option "Options" --> click icon "Keymap". Then search in the column "Shortcut" (can be ordered by clicking on the column header) for the shortcut you want to change.